# Must, should or cannot be empty?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

In the context of data that needs to be filled in in a computer program:
When a data field must be filled in, what is the best way to phrase this (specifically, in the pop-up window warning the users they forgot to fill it in)?

- The name cannot be empty.
- The name must not be empty.
- The name should not be empty.
- The name is mandatory.
- The name is required.
- The name must be filled in.
- (Anything else?)

Assume adult users.

They all seem equally valid to me...

Comment: They all seem equally valid because they *are* equally valid. As are all versions without ***The***, in your "Error message" context. Any preference is simply a matter of opinion, since no-one really expects the exact text in such contexts to adhere to "grammatical rules" as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers although "should" has a slightly different meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: @BobRodes: It would be stretching a point to claim any kind of "slightly different meaning" in OP's exact context. Presumably if the field is mandatory, that means you can't submit the form without filling it in. But I've never heard of a computer "warning message" telling me that a form has been accepted "under protest" (because I failed to did something I *ought* to have done, as opposed to an "error message" telling the transaction can't be processed because I didn't do something I *must* do).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. Nevertheless, I wouldn't choose *should* in this context, since, while it is adequate to convey the meaning, the other words are less dependent on the context to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *The name is required*, both because it is the simplest way to say what you are trying to say and because it is the usual way to say it in your use case.

All of the other ones say the same thing, with one exception. *The name should not be empty* does not mean that it *cannot* be empty. It is closer to the meaning of *The name is preferably not empty.*

Comment: I don't think a name can be empty or not empty. Only a field.

Comment: It is also always better to state things in the positive than the negative both for clarity, and friendliness

Comment: @Lambie True, but we're not referring to the HTML `name` attribute here. Rather, we're referring to a field that is asking for the name of the form filler.

Comment: Alright, but I still don't get understand saying a name cannot be empty. A field cannot be empty and must contain a name. Generally, under the field, one sees: The field must not be empty. Then, above the field or beside it, one sees: Name.

Comment: @lambie I don't think the user is concerned with the idea of "fields" at all, let alone the idea that such an entity has a name attribute. If a name is required in a form, and the user attempts to submit the form without providing it, my practice is to focus on the name field and display a message such as "please enter a name."

Comment: @BobRodes Oh, so a data field is not a field?

Comment: @Andrey What do you mean?

Comment: @Lambie If I can clarify my position in any way, I'll be glad to. But you'll have to ask questions that make sense. Hostility and belligerence tend to make that difficult, I might add.

Answer (score 1):

When writing computer software interfaces, user feedback should be as short but as informative as possible.  For this reason the most common feedback of this type is "X is *required*"

Side note: as BobRodes suggests in the above comment, a more modern approach is to highlight the field with the missing data and prevent form submission until the field is complete.  If there are special restrictions on what kind of data is required, then give targeted feedback to help the user understand what is missing.  Examples:

> Name must be at least five characters long and cannot contain any special characters like "/", "$", "%", "?" etc.
>
> Please enter a valid email address.
>
> Please select at least one option from the drop-down

Answer (score 0):

**This field must not be empty.**

The field name appears next to the empty field. Not in the sentence.

[examples abound of this sentence](https://www.google.com/search?ei=xI_DWtPSNu6P5wL0_rLwDQ&q=%22this%20field%20must%20not%20be%20empty%22&oq=%22this%20field%20must%20not%20be%20empty%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...16417.16914.0.17316.5.4.0.0.0.0.346.813.1j1j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.91...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13i30k1.0.9pw_oZ4W4cI)

Answer (score 0):

For decades (since the 1960s) the phrase that has been used to describe this situation would go like this:

> *Name* is a **[required field](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20a%20required%20field%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**.